# How can i make the text appear inside the input field

Tags: html, css

When I make an input button and add a label, the label appears on the side of the input field. How can I make it appear inside the input field?

I have tried to put the label inside the input field with CSS, but when I write in the input, the label and the text overlap, and the text becomes unreadable. How can I make the label disappear when I type in the input field? If you have any other options, please tell me.

```
    <div class="holder">
        <label>username</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
```

```
.holder {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .holder label {
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  }
  
  .holder input {
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 25px;
  }
```

Comment: You could position the input field above the label, and give it a transparent background. And when the input field has focus, or is not empty, you make it a solid background instead ... or something like that. Or perhaps research the keyword "floating labels", to get some approaches. (And you will also find explanations, why those are considered _bad_ in terms of usability. The biggest favor you can do your users, is to have the label text visible all the time.)

Comment: I suggest expanding your HTML knowledge a bit further. As you are doing something that is very bad practice. You want a placeholder, you can achieve that by just adding the attribute `placeholder="Username" within the input field same way you would add a class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="holder">
    <label>username</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="username">
</div>
```

Try this by adding placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `placeholder` attribute for the input tag. Like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML using the input **placeholder** attribute, show the text inside the input text
example:-

```
<input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
```